On Fubini-Tonelli for complete measures; Folland
I'm working on proving the Fubini-Tonelli theorem for complete measures in Folland's real analysis text. The theorem reads as follows

The exercise is:

49. Prove Theorem 2.39 by using Theorem 2.37 [the ordinary Fubini-Tonelli theorem] and Proposition 2.12 [see below] together with the following lemmas.
a. If $E\in\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}$ and $\mu\times\nu(E)=0$, then $\nu(E_x)=\mu(E^y)=0$ for a.e. $x$ and $y$.
b. If $f$ is $\mathcal{L}$-measurable and $f=0$ $\lambda$-a.e., then $f_x$ and $f^y$ are integrable for a.e. $x$ and $y$, and $\int f_x\,d\nu=\int f^y\,d\mu=0$ for a.e. $x$ and $y$ (Here the completeness of $\mu$ and $\nu$ is needed.)

Let $(X,\overline{\mathcal M},\overline{\mu})$ be the completion of $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$. Proposition 2.12 states that if $f$ is an $\overline{\mathcal M}$-measurable function, there is an $\mathcal M$-measurable function $g$ such that $f=g$ $\overline\mu$-a.e.
I feel confident about my solutions to part (a) and part (b) of the exercise, but I'm not sure how to use these, along with Proposition 2.12, to prove the theorem. My guess is that one somehow needs to apply the ordinary Fubini-Tonelli theorem, but what confuses me is that in the ordinary Fubini-Tonelli theorem the iterated integrals equal the integral with respect to the (incomplete) product measure, whereas in the Fubini-Tonelli theorem for complete measures the iterated integrals equal the integral with respect to the complete product measure.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
